# regex match multiple text in either single or double quote

Tags: regex

I want to match strings like:

```
The two sentences are 'He said "Hello there"' and "She said 'goodbye' and 'another sentence'"
```

where each sentence is delimited by either single or double quotes, and can contain the opposite double or single quotes inside the sentence.

The regex should return 2 matches - 1 for each sentence. For the example above:

```
He said "Hello there"
She said 'goodbye' and 'another sentence'
```

The following regex gets close:

```
^The two sentences are (?:'|")(.*)(?:'|") and (?:'|")(.*)(?:'|")$
```

But because the first expression group is greedy up to any single or double quote, the above example actually returns:

```
He said "Hello there"' and "She said 'goodbye
another sentence'
```

It would be really easy if I do something like:

```
^The two sentences are ('|")(.*)\1 and ('|")(.*)\3$
```

But then I also get back the matches for the capture groups - so I get back 4 matches - a single quote, the 1st sentence, a double quote, the 2nd sentence.

Any good ideas on how to do this sort of thing (matching start and end of string delimiters) while "throwing away" the delimiter matches before returning just what was matched inside the delimited strings?

Comment: This looks like a regex nightmare to me.  Better yet, you might want consider writing a rudimentary _parser_ to handle this.

Comment: Life would be really easy if there was a way to throw away some of the captured groups before returning the resulting matches. Then the references to captured groups could be used internally and then discarded.

Comment: @PhilDavis, can't you filter by yourself?

Comment: Are you using that in Python? Just use `re.finditer` and only grab `match.group(0)`

Comment: I want to use this type of construct in Behat/Gherkin steps, so I can say stuff like:
`^I create the folders "a folder with 'single' quotes" and 'a folder with "double" quotes'`
so that the person writing scenarios can make folder names that have either single or double quotes inside them, and enclose the folder/file name in the opposite double or single quotes.

The Behat/Gherkin engine has the regex parser built inside it, and passes the match(es) into the associated function/method. So I want the matches to be just the file names, not have the superfluous delimiters in the matches array

Comment: What you want to do is not possible without some modification of source code. It should only return Group 0 value.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two separate expressions.
You'll be best off handling them like this

```
("[^"]*"|'[^']*')
```

You probably need to bracket the individual parts to be able to use the `|`, but you should get the idea.

Comment: That is the kind of thing I am doing now. But it returns the "sentence" with the surrounding double or single quotes still on the ends. Ideally I do not want to return the surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on @daniu

Why dont you do this then?

`(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')`

https://regex101.com/r/hpuoia/1

Comment: That returns 2 capturing groups. If the sentence is surrounded by double quotes, then it comes back in group 1, if it is surrounded by single quotes it comes back in group 2. Using that on a 2-sentence example means there are 4 groups returned in total.
It would be really nice to get back each sentence in a single match each, without any other extraneous captured matches, and without the single or double quote delimiter on the ends of the returned sentence.